# Can't login on google via Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

My code is below. I constantly get an error: wrong password, but if I enter it manually, there is no error.

What could be the reason?

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import AdblockerPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker';
import AnonymizeUAPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua';
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
puppeteer.use(AnonymizeUAPlugin());
puppeteer.use(
    AdblockerPlugin({
        blockTrackers: true,
    })
);
async function login() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
        args: [
            '--start-maximized',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--window-size=800,800',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        ],
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    let login_link =
        'https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=mail&continue=https://google.com&hl=en';
    await page.goto(login_link, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    await page.type('input[type="email"]', 'email', { delay: 300 });
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    await page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]');
    await page.type('input[type="password"]', 'password', { delay: 300 });
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
}

login();
```

The password is entered, then Enter is pressed, at which point the password is erased and a message appears indicating that the password is incorrect.

If you look at the console, the following error appears:

Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-sTQkO2FTdYglm5ToNPeoSw' 'unsafe-inline'".